# Как правильно записывать информацию в базу sql запросом?

Tags: php, mysql

Как записать информацию в базу sql с поля ввода textarea с сохранением абзацев и переходов на новую строку?

Хочу записать текст:
"Всем привет!

Всем пока!"

Здесь есть пробел между строк.

Comment: `"Всем привет!\n\nВсем пока!"`

Comment: Нужен визевик типа [summernote](http://summernote.org/) или [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/download)

Comment: Оно как есть так и запишется в БД, со всеми переносами и пробелами.

Comment: Это выводить надо правильно, а не записывать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, Вам нужна функция [`nl2br()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php).

При внесении в БД оставлять без изменений, а выводить так:

```
echo '<div>',nl2br($text),'</div>';
```

Для `<textarea>` и `<pre>`:

```
echo '<textarea>',$text,'</textarea>';
echo '<pre>',$text,'</pre>';
```

Comment: Сделал с помощью <pre </pre>